# ubuntu 13.04 cant read windows 8 partition anymore

Tags: symbolic-link

I freshly installed ubuntu 13.04 on my Windows 8 PC. Dual booting it, I created a symbolic link while on ubuntu to my windows based Dropbox directory. The link worked fine while the computer was still on. I shut it down normally with a full shut down and when I turned it back on and it booted automatically into ubuntu, it didn't work anymore. I could no longer read the windows partitions and the link wasn't working. The error message I got said that it was because Windows was not shut down properly. I rebooted into windows and turned it off again to test it, but it didn't work.

Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the partition for windows 8 isn't mounted. If it's not mounted, you can't access it. You can test this out by opening nautilus and clicking on the drive for windows 8 and then trying the link you made. You'll need to mount that partition every time you turn on your computer or create a script to run everytime on boot to mount that parition.